# Perceptual (or average) image hashing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to calculate the perceptual hash of an image and should do it without using any external libraries.

I tried using pHash (http://phash.org/) but I wasn't able to compile it for iOS (5) and I haven't found a real tutorial on how to do it.

Comment: Please note pHash is licensed under GPLv3, which means that derived work can only be distributed under the same license terms!

Comment: That wouldn't be a problem (the code will be released under the same license. The problem is I can't compile pHash for iOS (arm).

Answer (score 0):

One (library-dependent) solution is to use the pHashing functionality added to ImageMagick in version 6.8.8.3, which has [iOS binaries available](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/iOS/).  Usage examples are documented [here](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/perceptual_hash_test_results_510/index.html).

Here's also a simple reference function (in C#) for generating your own comparable image average hash, found on [this blog](http://01101001.net/programming.php).

```
public static ulong AverageHash(System.Drawing.Image theImage)
// Calculate a hash of an image based on visual characteristics.
// Described at http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/432-Looks-Like-It.html
{
    // Squeeze the image down to an 8x8 image.
    // Chant the ancient incantations to create the correct data structures.
    Bitmap squeezedImage = new Bitmap(8, 8, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
    Graphics drawingArea = Graphics.FromImage(squeezedImage);
        drawingArea.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        drawingArea.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
        drawingArea.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        drawingArea.DrawImage(theImage, 0, 0, 8, 8);

    byte[] grayScaleImage = new byte[64];

    uint averageValue = 0;
    ulong finalHash = 0;

    // Reduce to 8-bit grayscale and calculate the average pixel value.
    for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        {
            Color pixelColour = squeezedImage.GetPixel(x,y);
            uint grayTone = ((uint)((pixelColour.R * 0.3) + (pixelColour.G * 0.59) + (pixelColour.B * 0.11)));

            grayScaleImage[x + y*8] = (byte)grayTone;
            averageValue += grayTone;
        }
    }
    averageValue /= 64;

    // Return 1-bits when the tone is equal to or above the average,
    // and 0-bits when it's below the average.
    for(int k = 0; k < 64; k++)
    {
        if(grayScaleImage[k] >= averageValue)
        {
            finalHash |= (1UL << (63-k));
        }
    }

    return finalHash;
}
```